# Bootstrap form horizontal alignment not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want my email and password to appear on same line but it is not working. please help me.

```
 <div class="container">
                  <form >
                      <fieldset class="form-group row">
                          <label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" />
                          </div>
                      </fieldset>
                      <fieldset class="form-group row">
                          <label for="password" class="control-label col-sm-2">Password</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                          </div>
                      </fieldset>
                      <fieldset class="form-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>                  
                      </fieldset>
                  </form>
              </div>
```

Comment: It's clearly stated how to do that. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline

Answer (score -1):

make sure your code is like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"
 placeholder="Enter First Name">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"
 placeholder="Enter Last Name">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
 <div class="checkbox">
 <label>
 <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
 </label>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
                  <form >
                    <fieldset class="form-group row">
                    <div style="float: left;">

                          <label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" />
                          </div>


                    </div>
                     <div style="margin-left: 250px">
                          <label for="password" class="control-label col-sm-2">Password</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                          </div>
                          </div>
                    </fieldset>



                      <fieldset class="form-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>                  
                      </fieldset>
                  </form>
              </div>
```

Comment: You can try different  css options

Comment: Could you add some information around that code in an [edit]?

Comment: sorry I forgot it I'm new in here :D